# Is there a function $f(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)$ is unique for all positive integer values $x$ and $y$?

Tags: functions

Is there a function $f(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)$ is unique for $x > 0, y > 0$ and $x$ and $y$ are both integers. Also, how do you prove that $f(x,y)$ is indeed unique?

Comment: What do you mean with $f(x,y)$ being unique? Every thing is unique.

Comment: I mean f(x,y) will never be equal to f(a,b) or f(a,x) or f(y,b) or f(y,x).

Comment: Look under pairing functions.

Comment: @Wes I think you want to find $f$ such that $f$ is defined on $\mathbb Z^+×\mathbb Z^+$ and $f$ is injective.

Comment: You could also have $f:\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Q}$ via $f(x,y)=x.y$, i.e. $f(3,5)=3.5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a consequence of the uniqueness of the decomposition into a product of prime factors, the function
$$
f(x,y) = 2^x3^y
$$
is injective.